# Store Variables in Lists python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have tried to do this, and I think its clear what I want, I want to store the message variables that I have made in a List and then use this for printing, I wonder why does this not work?

```
items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
message1 = "This is " + items[0] + "its color is red"
message2 = "This is " + items[1] + "its color is blue"
message3 = "This is " + items[2] + "it has no color yet"
messages = ['message1', 'message2', 'message3']
for message in messages:
    print(message)
```

The output is:

```
message1
message2
message3
```

Comment: Get rid of the `'` marks around the variable names. Replace `messages = ['message1', 'message2', 'message3']` with `messages = [message1,message2, message3]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the quote marks

```
messages = [message1, message2, message3]
```

Currently you're just printing strings and not variables

also, this

```
for message in messages:
    print(messages)
```

will print the whole list `messages` 3 times. Change to `print(message)` to print each item in the list

Answer (score 3):

```
message1 = "This is " + items[0] + "its color is red"
message2 = "This is " + items[1] + "its color is blue"
message3 = "This is " + items[2] + "it has no color yet"
messages = [message1, message2, message3] # Note there are no quotes now
for message in messages:
    print(messages)
```

You were really close, but you're making a list of strings and not variables. Just take the quotes out!

Answer (score 2):

This is a list of strings:

```
['message1', 'message2', 'message3']
```

What you are looking for is a list of variables:

```
[message1, message2, message3]
```