# Python storing variables in a list

Tags: python

If I want to store the variable '`boo`' in a list, how would I go about doing so?

Would it be correct to write the following:

```py
boo = list(first_name)
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `first_name`?

Comment: @anonuser, try it and inspect the result. You may be surprised :-)

Comment: What is "correct" depends on what you want the result to be. I suggest you read a tutorial or watch a video on python lists.

Comment: Haha ok, I think it might have been a bit of a stupid question, thank you all nevertheless :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54895119/5468463

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list in Python using the `[]` characters, the `list()` **converts** whatever you pass into it to a list, it is not used for *defining* a list itself.

For instance, to create a new list:

```py
newList = ["one", "two", "three"] # Create a list of three string elements.

print(newList[0]) # Outputs "one"
print(newList[1]) # Outputs "two"
print(newList[2]) # Outputs "three"
```

To convert a string to a list:

```py
list("hello") # Creates the list -> ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
boo = 10
boo = [boo]
print(boo)
[out][10]
a = 9
boo.append[a]
print(boo)
[out][10,9]
```

in this ways the boo variable is converted to a normal list

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).